# Crystal Reports - Is it possible to suppress a label or picture based upon a formula?

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to suppress a label and image if certain data is encountered.

Is this possible in Crystal Reports with a formula, or by some other means?

Comment: Should probably go to http://superuser.com

Comment: No, Crystal Reports is definitely programming related.

Comment: I guess it depends. Excel is programming related if you get into VBA. I guess I just was going by our organization. We have Super Users do this sort of thing here. You're right though, a lot of things in CR are programming related.

Comment: One of these comments makes the site better. Two of these comments dilute the content... and I see this OFTEN. Let's get back to the focus of these sites -- asking, answering, and improving/modifying questions. Does the question need moved? Move it. Does the question fall into a gray area? Have a discussion on META about fixing the gray area.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The label suppression attribute supports formulas - click the weird button to the left of the checkbox.  It's been there since at least v8.5.

Can't say for images - see if there's the ability to suppress them at all.  I've created a section to hold them in the past, and dealt with visibility of the section if that helps.

Comment: Beat me to it! Yes, you can suppress images the same as anything else.  If the suppression formula evaluates to true, the image is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I have been fencing with this for a while and finally found out how to do it. Yes, Put an image on the header, then if you want the image to only appear depending on the companyid use the suppress button. add the image and then (R) click it and select the properties, useing the general TAB select the button to the right of the suppress tic box. 
(dont put a tic in the box) just, select the X2 button and put something like this in the code area.>             `{companyid} in [56,57,58]`
companyid is a column in a table being displayed on the page and as it is from the data source and is being  displayed the system will display on the image when the companyid data  is in the list shown. i.e 56 or 57 or 58.    The system does not seem to like parameter values when doing this test. but works well if you can make it use data for the test.

Comment: You might want to answer more clearly next time. Rather than posting in paragraph post in points so that its more readable. Just trying to help.